# datepicker returns 01-01-1970

Tags: php, datepicker

I am unable to fix this issue.I have my code below

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="start_date"><?php echo lang('enable_on');?></label>
            <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'start_date', 'data-value'=>assign_value('start_date', reverse_format($start_date)), 'class'=>'datepicker form-control']);?>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="end_date"><?php echo lang('disable_on');?></label>
            <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'end_date', 'data-value'=>assign_value('end_date', reverse_format($end_date)), 'class'=>'datepicker form-control']); ?>
        </div>
```

and the controller code here

```
 $save['start_date'] = \CI::input()->post('start_date');
 $save['end_date'] = \CI::input()->post('end_date');
```

to save the two dates accordingly.I have tried to
 date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date)) but still no luck.

Comment: which framework do you use? what does form_input() needs as parameters? what is written in $start_date and $end_date?

Comment: i am using gocart which is built in codeigniter3,the code works fine,its just the dates that are messed up after using datepicker

Comment: thats why it would be good to know, what is in $start_date and $end_date. this way we could provide you better help

Comment: here is the html generated with the code above <div class="form-group">
                <label for="end_date">Disable On (UTC)</label>
                <input type="text" name="end_date" value="01-01-1970" class="datepicker form-control">
            </div>

Comment: this is not what i wanted :'D If $start_date is already messed up, it is no wonder that the value will be returning 01-01-1970 because thats basic timestamp if no other value is provided

Comment: it looks like datepicker uses slashes like 27/03/2017 and then i convert it to 2017-03-27 using this date('Y-m-d',strtotime($start_date)) but this format is changed it saves 1970.i cant figure it out

Comment: Have you tried to change the datepicker settings to not use slashes? and strtotime has no idea what "27/03/2017" means so it will return 01-01-1970

Comment: yes $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });